# Linear Algebra (Transformation)

Tags: linear-transformations, transformation, matrix-equations

I want to calculate $\hat{X}$ from a simple matrix equation,
\begin{equation}
\hat{A}\hat{X} = \hat{B}
\end{equation}
in which $\hat{A}$, $\hat{B}$, and $\hat{X}$ are all square $N\times N$ matrices. However, the matrices are very large and solving for $\hat{X}$ is practically impossible.

Considering that in the end, I want to use $\hat{X}$ to get $\vec{u} = \vec{P}\hat{X}$, is there anyway to directly solve for $\vec{u}$?
($\vec{P}$ and $\vec{u}$ are both $1\times N$ vectors.)

Answer (score 1):

You want to find
$$
P A^{-1} B
$$
You can do this by first finding 
$$
Q = P A^{-1}
$$
and then finding $QB$.

Finding $Q$ amounts to solving 
$$
QA = P
$$
or, equivalently
$$
A^t Q^t = P^t. 
$$

Solving for $Q^t$ in this situation using a linear-equation solver is generally much faster than inverting $A$.

Approximate matlab code (untested):

```
function z = solvenoei(A, B, p)
% A and B are n x n; p is 1 x n. 

qt = A' \ p'; % find q^t
z = qt' * B;
```